# Counting tokens in compilers, lexical analyser

Tags: compilers, lexical-analysis

Let's start with the question.  Say I have a C language statements follows

1. it 458cat 2.01 = 96.87abc a.2 ;

   -my question is how many tokens are there in the above statements. Secondly does white space like tabs, newline, makes a token or not?
2. If you are interested in my solution then  proceed on your own risk. Firstly I think in lexical analyser there is no such thing as white space so after removal of that the above statement would look catastrophic so, I have not taking that approach.
3. Now we see 'it' as an identifier similarly, '458' as integer, 'cat' as identifier, (please not that I may have mistaken here which i don't know that is '458cat' may be invalid identifier so the lexical analyser may report an error, but I don't know will that happen or not. you may argue that what I have written is wrong because  if it was true then the identifier like '678hello' will be a valid identifier but since its not then iam wrong. But take a different approach like if all white space between '468   abc' being vanished (this is what lexical analyser does first) then it would like '468abc' . Initially in case of  468 abc we were taking 468 as integer and abc as valid identifier but after  white space removal things are changed so what I think is it will be reported in syntax analyser  but I don't know that am I right), similarly, '2.01' as real integers, '=' as operator, '96.87' as real number, 'abc' as identifier, 'a ' as identifier, .2 as real number and ' ; ' as special symbol.
4. I most certainly know that iam not right but if you could correct where I was  wrong it will be helpful

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be specific to the C programming language. It may be on-topic at [so].

Comment: @david: there are many who would say it's off-topic in SO because it has nothing to do *programming*, being an implementation detail of a particular compiler. However, tokenisation is specified by the C standard and it is has an effect on writing preprocessor macros (in certain obscure constructs) so it would fit into the language-lawyer tag. I fear that type of discussion wouldnot be at a level consistent with OP's expectations. Anyway, it's been asked before and answered (by me, amongst others) so even on-topic it would be a dupe.

Comment: In short, although it is evidently a homework problem in certain CS courses, it seems to fall into a blackhole in SE. It's a question; it has an objective answer; people studying CS want to know the answer, but...

Answer (score 1):

In C, `458cat` is a single *ppnumber* token. It's not a valid number, so it will eventually produce an error message, but it is tokenised as a single token.

There's a longer explanation of this behaviour [in this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49365061/1566221).

Comment: Well thanks for answering but my point is what I could change 458cat to 888889aprilfool

Comment: @low_burning: it would still be a single *ppnumber*. Maybe I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Firstly thanks for support and secondly I have understood and thirdly rici if I knew that there is a question that exists already I would have never asker it. Fourthly you always get an answer but through stack exchange it's pretty quick and by self it takes times and many reasoned assertion to reach a verdict and that is why I ask here. But you keep doing what you are doing. I wished I could have an up vote for you